# Difference between req.session and req.app and app.set in express

Tags: node.js, express

What us the difference between req.session vs req.app vs app.set in Express app. Say I have redis session store. Are they all saved in a session store, or memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express doesn't have session handling implementation in its core. You have to use [session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) middleware which is then used to handle the sessions. (it's installed automatically via express-generator)

If you have a look at the documentation of the session module you'll see that it can use different types of storage to store your session data. Memory is used by default and should only be used for your development purpose due to as-designed memory leak. For production you can use store of your choice such as [connect-redis](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis), [connect-mysql](https://github.com/nlf/connect-mysql) and many others.

To answer your questions :

- The middleware then exposes `req.session` which you can use to access
  session data.
- `req.app` is a reference to express application instance and has
  nothing to do with sessions.
- `app.set` is used to set application level locals and has nothing to
  do with sessions.
- When you use RedisStore then your session data are stored in Redis
  database.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Redis Store to store sessions. Which one out of three mentioned above is ideal for temporary data storage per session?

Comment: Depends on your needs but in general yes, redis is a good choice for session storage as it's in-memory database therefore very fast to access the data

Comment: I meant which one out of req.session vs req.app vs app.set

Answer (score 0):

`req.app` is a reference to the Express `app` object that was associated with the route handler that is handling the current request.  This allows you to more easily get to that `app` object, particularly if routes are defined in separate modules.

So, if you did something like this:

```
app.get('/viewdirectory', require('./mymiddleware.js'))
```

Then, that middleware would be able to reach the `app` object via `req.app` during a request where it otherwise wouldn't have that ability without manually passing the `app` object in a less convenient module constructor.

`app.set()` is an ability to set various configuration options on the `app` object.  Those options are documented [here](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.set).

`req.session` is a session object used by some session middleware.  Express does not come pre-configured with built-in session management.  There are many different session add-ons for Express.  Some of them use middleware that places the session in `req.session` so you can easily access it in any request handler.  Putting the session reference in `req.session` is a common convention to make it easy for request handlers to get to when servicing a request.

Where the session is actually stored for the longer duration outside of a request depends upon the particular session implementation.  Some session are just stored in JS objects in memory.  Some are stored in a shared in-memory database like redis.  Some are stored in a regular, file-based database.  Some session implementations allow you to pick which type of session storage you want to use.